# Vertical Scrollbar Bug IE9 and IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9, scrollbar

Why does IE9 and IE7 display the vertical scroll bar incorrectly when the width of a div is programatically set to the width of the viewport and the overflow property is programatically set to auto...

In IE9 the scroll bar is displayed 17 pixels to far to the left.
In IE7 the scroll bar is displayed 17 pixels to far to the left and there is a disabled scroll bar next to it.

Here is a webpage to illustrate:

http://www.sweetkarma.net/iebug

MORE INFO: After asking this question I did a little more searching and found this:

Seems like IE9 doesn't handle the box-sizing property correctly - changing it from "border-box" to "content-box" or leaving it blank will fix your problem.

This fixes the problem in IE9 but not IE7.

Answer (score 0):

The IE border-box model counts the padding and margins as part of the element. So, you can do two things:

- Explicitly set padding and margin to zero
- Calculate the default margin and padding and subtract that from the dynamic width

**References**

- [Exploring the Box Ocean in Explorer - Boxing with CSS, Part II: No Margin For Error](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial10/4.html)
- [Standards and CSS in IE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2005/07/29/445242.aspx)
- [Quirksmode: box-sizing](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html)